# How to suppress/control logging of Wagon-FTP Maven extension?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3, wagon, maven-wagon-plugin

I'm deploying Maven site by FTP, using [Wagon-FTP](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-ftp/). Works fine, but output is full of FTP connection/authentication details, which effectively expose logins and passwords to everybody (especially if the project is open source and its CI protocols are publicly accessible):

```
[...]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3:deploy (default-deploy) @ rempl ---
Reply received: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 09:08. Server port: 21.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Command sent: USER ****

Reply received: 331 User **** OK. Password required

Command sent: PASS ********

Reply received: 230-User **** has group access to: ***
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
[...]
```

Is it possible to suppress this logging? Or configure it... This is a section of my `pom.xml`, where Wagon-FTP is used:

```
[...]
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    [...]
</build>
[...]
```

Comment: We reported it: [WAGON-320](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/WAGON-320)

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, and basically it is related to maven site plugin and not the wagon ftp (which is only a simple adapter for the apache-commons-net ftp client). See the [source of AbstractDeployPlugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-site-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/site/AbstractDeployMojo.java?view=markup) from line 310.

```
   Debug debug = new Debug();

   wagon.addSessionListener( debug );

   wagon.addTransferListener( debug );
```

Where [Debug](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/wagon/trunk/wagon-provider-api/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wagon/observers/Debug.java?view=markup) is using the standard output.

IMHO the nice solution would be to use a more sophisticated SessionListener or a flag to avoid addSessionListener(debug) if not needed in the Wagon source.