# Suppress upload messages of maven deploy

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

we are using Bamboo for Continuous Integration and deploy successful tests to our snapshot repository with a simple `mvn deploy` statement. Unfortunately this produces thousands of lines like this:

```
20-Apr-2012 10:38:44    28688 KB   
20-Apr-2012 10:38:44    28692 KB   
20-Apr-2012 10:38:44    28696 KB
...
20-Apr-2012 10:38:57    Uploaded: https://xxx (31932 KB at 7496.0 KB/sec)
```

This appears in Bamboo:

```
The Build generated 14,979 lines of output. The output is too long and has been
truncated to the last 1,000 lines. Download full Build log.
```

So it's possible to download the full log, but's full of the upload messages. Is it possible to suppress the lines above in `mvn deploy` and only output a summary?

Comment: Is it being run on Windows or on Unix? I believe that you can grep out the messages you don't desire

Comment: Looks like you are stuck in terms of suppressing, they are using System.out for their debug printouts. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564018/how-to-suppress-control-logging-of-wagon-ftp-maven-extension

Comment: @Vic: it's linux. I don't think I can manually grep some stuff. It's a Bamboo Maven-Task and I only can configure the maven goals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution to suppress the output of the lines:

```
20-Apr-2012 10:38:44    28688 KB   
20-Apr-2012 10:38:44    28692 KB   
20-Apr-2012 10:38:44    28696 KB
```

is to you the -B option on command. This is the --batch-mode option for Maven which suppresses the output of the above.